# Blender 2.78 Nvidia Grid on Amazon EC2 g2.8xlarge

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've just managed to set up an amazon g2.8xlarge ec2 instance and got it running using vnc.
i've installed Blender  2.78 and set the render engine to GPU, Cuda Grid K.520 x4
and did a test render on both amazon and my own pc (GTX 980) [GPU Render].

[image]

on amazon with 4gpus i rendered this on 2min44s and on my rig 4min33 s

yeah, render time was half but also need to keep in mind that at the time that i was rendering i had 2 monitors on and one of them is 4k .

i don't know if i'm doing something wrong or this is what it is supposed to be!
i would be happy if anyone can help on this !

i'm running windows 2012 RC2 on amazon btw.

Comment: You can use an alternative render which is more advanced like luxrender (free) to render.It has awesome device handling you can even use gpus + cpus simultaneously .

Comment: An other cause for this is that the Cpu in your amazon server might not have many pci lanes